# Assume we have $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$ with $p$ being a prime. Prove that $x^{p-1}-1=(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know how this formula works and it is quite interesting actually but how would you prove this relationship?  Through induction (seems difficult since there's no equation for prime numbers), but I'm not sure if there is any other way to show this equation.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean $x^{p-1}-1 = (x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-(p-1))$

Comment: The two polynomials are of degree $p-1$. Their difference has $p-1$ distinct roots, so by general field results it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas And they are both monic. That's important!

Comment: @AndréNicolas: in ${\mathbf Z}_3[x]$, $x^2$ and $2x^2-1$ each have degree $2$ and their difference $x^2-1$ has 2 distinct roots but is not the zero polynomial (Pedro made a comment while I was about to write the same thing, so I give an example instead.)

Comment: Yes, I did specify small degree but forgot to say monic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_p^* = \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is a group of order $p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the simple fact that if $gcd(x,a)=1$ then, $x^{\phi(a)} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod a})$.

Here, $gcd(x,p)=1 \Rightarrow x^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod p}) \Rightarrow x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod p}) \Rightarrow \forall z \in \mathbb{Z}_p,\  z^{p-1}-1 =0$. This is enough to factor the polynomial in to a product of linear factors where all of it's roots lie in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.